# Calculate percentage in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My db looks like:

```
{
  {user:bob,votes:63}
  {user:jack,votes:27}
  {user:john,votes:10}
}
```

I can get the total of the votes, but I can't figure out how to get each persons vote as a percentage of the total. For example; jack would have 27% of the vote.

```
[ 
  {
    '$group': { 
                '_id': '',
                'totalofvotes': {'$sum': '$votes'},
                '%votesperperson': {'$multiply':[{'$divide':["votes",{'$sum': '$votes'}]},100]}                   
              },
  }
]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can't do this in a single group stage, as group as to be terminated for having sum value. Instead, use the following query :

```
db['test'].aggregate(
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
            _id:null,
            sum:{$sum:"$votes"},
            users:{$push:{user:"$user", votes:"$votes"}}
            }
        },
        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$users",

            }
        },
        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {user:"$users.user",
              votes:"$users.votes",
              sum:"$sum",
                "percent": {$multiply:[{$divide:["$users.votes","$sum"]},100]}
            }
        },
    ]
);
```

It will output

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "user" : "bob", 
    "votes" : NumberInt(63), 
    "sum" : NumberInt(100), 
    "percent" : 63.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "user" : "jack", 
    "votes" : NumberInt(27), 
    "sum" : NumberInt(100), 
    "percent" : 27.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "user" : "john", 
    "votes" : NumberInt(10), 
    "sum" : NumberInt(100), 
    "percent" : 10.0
}
```

Comment: Thanks @matthPen
I've stepped through this with print() and I understand now.

Comment: For future readers: one might want to use `$replaceRoot` instead of having to manually project all sub fields back to root fields.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Domino in the accepted answer, if you have a long list of fields and don't want to project them all manually, you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to promote the document that was grouped in the first stage.

```js
db.col.aggregate(
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
              _id: null,
              sum: { $sum: "$votes" },
              users: {
                $push: {
                  user: "$user", votes: "$votes"
                }
              }
            }
        },
        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: { path : "$users" }
        },
        // Stage 3
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
              $mergeObjects: [{
                percent: { $multiply:[{ $divide: ["$users.votes", "$sum"]}, 100] }
              }, "$users"]
            }
          }
        }
    ]
);
```

[live example](https://www.humongous.io/app/playground/mongodb/cxGHeTfgCoWF)